# AttributeError: module 'pygame.font' has no attribute 'SySFont'

Tags: python, pygame

When I want to execute the program the following error occurs:

> AttributeError: module 'pygame.font' has no attribute 'SySFont'

How can i fix it?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
windowSurface=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0 ,32)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
baseFont = pygame.font.SySFont(None, 48)
text = baseFont.render('x',True,white,blue)
simpleText = text.get_rect()
simpleText,centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
simpleText,centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery
windowSurface.blit(text,simpleText)
```

Comment: It's `SysFont`, not `SySFont`...

Comment: @AndreMotta That would be useless because `pygame.init()` already initializes all sub modules.

Comment: @sloth OMG what a stupid fail

Answer (score 0):

`SysFont` should be used rather than `SySFont`.

*Note: adding answer from comments since no other answer exists.*